# How to integrate Spring Security and Struts2

Tags: java, spring, security, struts2, spring-security

I've done tons of googling regarding this issue and up to now I could not  find any tutorial regarding integrating Struts2 and Spring Security.

My question is that How would I integrate Spring  Security and Struts2?

Where I want certain actions or pages to be restricted, like the admin page/url should be accessed only by an administrator and other things like that if a user tried to accessed that page he or she would be redirected to another page.

Comment: And with what exactly you are having problems?

Comment: I do not have any idea where to start, a simple example from the ground up would do.

Comment: Just follow some spring-security tutorial/example.

Comment: wouldn't there be any change to Struts2 Action classes? or struts2.xml? would I just really put a security.xml?

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you need to secure what's accessible on the `/admin/*` path. You need to declare the Spring Security Filter in your `web.xml`, the Struts filter should come after so that if you are accessing `/admin` it will be Spring Security that handle the request first and will be able to let it pass or block it depending on the role of the user:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You then declare your spring security context:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />           
    <form-login login-page="/login" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

I propose that you use the `struts2-convention` plugin so that URLs like `/login` are bound automatically to a class named let's say `com.foo.bar.actions.LoginAction`. Same for `LogoutAction`

Now what is under `/admin/*` should be secured by Spring Security, and the rest should be forwarded directly to the Struts2 filter.

Finally, in your JSP you can check if someone is an Admin with:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   <p>you are an admin</p>
</sec:authorize>
```

The rest can be found in any Spring Security tutorial. What's really important is the order of the filters declaration, spring security must be first.

**Edit:** searching on google, there is also [this link](http://jtechspace.blogspot.fr/2012/07/integrating-struts2-with-spring.html) that can be of help for you.

Comment: wouldn't I annotate hasRole inside an action class?

Comment: If you need to do it in a Java action class you can check it with `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")`

Comment: are there any tutorials regarding annotations? specifically for struts2?

Comment: there is a plugin named `struts2-annotation`: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/struts-2-annotations.html and also for spring security like `@PreAuthorize` etc http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Comment: if I download the struts2-annotation will it automatically have that @PreAuthorize?

Comment: no `@PreAuthorize` is from spring security. Struts annotations are `@Action` for example.

Comment: do I nee another jar for @PreAuthorize maybe like Spring-struts2 annotation? or something like that?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually very simple - Spring Security is web framework agnostic :)

You need to define Spring Security filter chain - this is a Java Filter that should be mapped to all requests. The filter will check if the path requires any privilages and if so checks if user is logged in and has those privilages.

Simple setup example.

web.xml (insert to your existing one, alongside struts config):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Spring security configuration (in the file mentioned in web.xml in contextConfigLocation parameter):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <http-basic/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" />
</http>
</beans:beans>
```

You may extend this as you wish - [Spring's documentation is rather well written](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)

You may go along an even simpler auto-config:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```

Above options secure your web-app per request path. You may want to secure the actions as well. Adding the below would get you going:

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class = "true" />
```

Let me know what features you need and I can point you in a direction. Keep in mind that namespace config is not a silver bullet - if you need a very custom solution you might need to configure all the spring beans yourself, but the documentation explains this well.

Comment: I'll look into it Spring Security first. then I'll get back here

Comment: @theadam spring's doc link broken

Comment: @granz Thanks for the tip, updated now. They have migrated the documentation. The link works now.