# Security Framework (JSP Field Level + method level)

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a Struts2 application. I am trying to add some Security to the app.

I need the following features :

1.) What fields the user can see/edit in JSP depending on his security permissions

2.) What actions the user can invoke.

3.) Preferably this security details should be configurable in a DB

Any recommendations ?

Comment: Are you using Spring? Spring Security is pluggable and meets these requirements, see the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333999/how-to-integrate-spring-security-and-struts2